# Make GIT auto-commit every file change

Tags: php, git, github, synchronization, sftp

I know that this was already asked, but I want to share my situation also to focus on alternative solutions and tips. We develop PHP websites, and we test everything on a remote semi-production server, to see how our web applications work in the real world.

Usually, we mount remote SFTP on our computers, and read/write directly on the server (then we have a nightly backup from the test server to another), so we haven't to save-and-upload every file we change.

Now we are considering to switch to GitHub to track file changes. I already installed and configured GitHub on my Mac, and a webhook that automatically pull from our GIT repository to out test web server. So, when I commit and sync to GitHub, I can refresh the page(s) I changed in my browser to see it in action.

The problem is that web scripting is often made of many micro-changes, sometimes you have to continuously hit "save" and switch to the browser to check if it works correctly... so having to commit (and specify a summary!) everytime is unacceptable.

How we can solve this problem with the workflow?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you continue using SFTP with GIT? They are not mutually exclusive

Comment: Surely you develop locally too? Make your changes hit save, test locally, commit working modified files at the end of the day! No issue there.

Comment: @Dale you should commit chunks with changes that are related, and if you will commit as rarely as once per day - you will have mega-commits where you cannot trace any changes, which are hard to merge or rollback. _but maybe you meant **pushing** once per day ?_

Comment: c69 Thanks yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put: you shouldn't do that.

Source code management systems are not for testing and transferring your code under development to testing servers. You should either work with SFTP as before or set up rsync. These are the tools for transfer.

You should use GitHub to store only working, complete changes. After testing your "micro-changes" and getting to a working snapshot you should commit and describe everything you modified since the last commit.

Anything else would be just hacking the tools you try to use. Doing what you propose would just mean loosing (nearly) all benefits that git gives you and would be much less convenient than using plain sftp/rsync.

Answer (score 4):

Commit only good code. Test with sftp if you have to, but only commit good code.

Losing a benefit like `git bisect` is a pretty serious side-effect of what you're proposing among others.